# Increasing max_old_space_size during production build of Angular app not working

Tags: node.js, angular

As my Angular project has grown substantially in size, I've repeatedly had to increase the size of the memory that Node.JS allocates. Unfortunately, even after increasing beyond **8192mb** using **max_old_space_size**, like so:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --source-map=false --prod && ng run SimpleWebTool:server:production
```

I'm getting the error. What doesn't make sense is the fact that it appears to not be trying to use more than 2GB.

```
chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.js (polyfills) 35.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.js (polyfills-es5) 128 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es2015.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.js (main) 12.9 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.js (main) 13.6 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.css (styles) 8.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-03-02T04:35:57.079Z - Hash: bdeba447e288f4c17cef - Time: 2021216ms

<--- Last few GCs --->

[11208:000001C1C72F4BC0]    43868 ms: Mark-sweep 2034.6 (2079.5) -> 2033.6 (2063.3) MB, 121.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 359.0 ms in 80 steps since start of marking, biggest step 6.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 495 ms) (average mu = 0.122, current mu = 0.030) f[11208:000001C1C72F4BC0]    44692 ms: Mark-sweep 2039.1 (2063.3) -> 2037.9 (2067.8) MB, 420.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 387.7 ms in 87 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 824 ms) (average mu = 0.062, current mu = 0.020) a

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF702D2463D]
Security context: 0x0129bab408a1 <JSObject>
    1: scan [000001437CE73D51] [C:\Users\User\Desktop\SimpleWebTool\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~7985] [pc=00000385E6A656AA](this=0x0277dd7a8379 <Object map = 00000304A3035541>)
    2: parseTokenNode(aka parseTokenNode) [00000277DD792899] [C:\Users\User\Desktop\SimpleWebTool\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~18140] [pc=00000385E68DF6...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF70215232F napi_wrap+124543
 2: 00007FF7020F36A6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+34502
 3: 00007FF7020F4366 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+37766
 4: 00007FF7028F8C5E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7028E0CA1 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF7027AE56C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF7027B9910 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF7027B6444 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF7027ABCD3 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF7027B2404 v8::internal::Heap::GlobalSizeOfObjects+212
11: 00007FF7027E8AEB v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts+907
12: 00007FF7025391F9 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+10121
13: 00007FF702D2463D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+567949
14: 00000385E6A656AA
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR!
```

Comment: What would happen if you run the command without ```&& ng run SimpleWebTool:server:production``` ?

Comment: And what is your node version?

Comment: Running Node v. 12.14.1

Answer (score 0):

My project is using the same method to deal with javascript memory issue. As far as I tried, node 10 works fine with above solution.

Comment: I tried downgrading to Node 10 with package.json but ran into the same problem.